# Identify the roots for the equation: $(x-2)(x-6i)(x+6i)= 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$(x-2)(x-6i)(x+6i)= 0$$I'm not exactly sure if I fully understand this question. If I'm not mistaken, I managed to get the results: $r_1=2, r_2=6i$, and $r_3=-6i$. However I'm not entirely certain that this is correct. I would really appreciate if anyone could work out and explain how they managed to get an answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to check then you could try expanding  the polynomial to something like $x^3-2x^2 +36x -72$ and then seeing if these results give zero.

Comment: @Henry Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @mrf: Peace of mind. $2$ is obviously a root of the original equation, but if you are "not entirely certain that this is correct" then calculating  $2^3-2\times 2^2 +36\times 2 -72$ and seeing that it is zero may reassure you that you have not made an error. Similarly checking $(6i)^3-2\times (6i)^2 +36\times 6i -72$

Comment: @Henry It is a gazillion times easier to just plug in $2$, $6i$ and $-6i$ in the factored version.

Comment: @mrf: Indeed it is.  The roots are obvious and clearly each give zero for the factored version.  But for some people a longer check can provide some extra reassurance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(x-2)(x-6i)(x+6i)=0$$
$$\iff x-2=0\ \ \text{or}\ \ x-6i=0\ \ \text{or}\ \ x+6i=0$$
$$\iff x=2\ \ \text{or}\ \ x=6i\ \ \text{or}\ \ x=-6i.$$
So, you are right.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So whenever I see these kinds of question, the answer is always the inverse?

Comment: @JoshuaLajoie: What you want to say is correct : $x+a=0\Rightarrow x=-a$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was that simple.
$\,\,\!\!\,\,\!\!$